# R gives Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘igraph’ in windows

Tags: r, windows, igraph

when i try to run  **library(igraph)** in **R version 3.2.3** i get the following error

```
> library(igraph)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘magrittr’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘igraph’
```

I am using windows 8,First i installed igraph package from local file (by downloading the zip file from http://igraph.org/r/)

help me....thanks in advance

Comment: igraph needs magrittr (and possibly other packages as well), so you need to install that first.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of installing packages with dependencies for R is using the REPL.

Example:

```
 install.packages("igraph")
```

Please try to install your package this way.

Comment: thankyou sir....and please tell me how to install REPL..

Comment: Copy paste what I wrote to the R shell.

Comment: it gave the following:Warning: unable to access index for repository http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.2/bioc/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.2/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.2/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.2/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘igraph’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)

Comment: It seems you don't have access to the R repositories. You can find more about this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/127508